Converting an algebric expression into a matrix form
Consider the following expression:
a1 b1 c1 + a4 b2 c1 + a7 b3 c1 + a2 b1 c2 + a5 b2 c2 + a8 b3 c2 + 
 a3 b1 c3 + a6 b2 c3 + a9 b3 c3

Can Mathematica convert it smarter into the product of a row vector, a 3*3 matrix, and a column vector?
Edited:
ex = a1^2 w1 + a1 a2 w2 + a1 a3 w3 + a1 a4 w4 + a1 a2 x1 + a2^2 x2 + 
   a2 a3 x3^2 + a2 a4 x4^3 + a1 a3 y1 + a2 a3 y2 + a3^2 y3^4 + 
   a3 a4 y4 + a1 a4 z1 + a2 a4 z2 + a3 a4 z3^2 + a4^2 z5;

Now, the matrices should be 4*4.

putting  higher powers terms like a^2 and y3^4 and so on might make it not possible to solve as there will be many different possibilities now.  I mean  a a^2 a gives a^4 and  a a^3 and so on. I mean there is now many different ways to generate possible solutions (if there is any) because of this.

@Nasser: I don't think the higher powers are any issue. The code even does not work for the linear power of a's for the 4*4 arrays.  Please try without power terms.

I think CoefficientArrays is what you are after.
I start by putting in your expression and defining two vectors of coefficients.
ex = a1  b1  c1 + a4  b2  c1 + a7  b3  c1 + a2  b1  c2 + a5  b2  c2 + 
a8  b3  c2 + a3  b1  c3 + a6  b2  c3 + a9  b3  c3;
vec1 = {b1, b2, b3};
vec2 = {c1, c2, c3};

Next we apply CoefficientArrays. You could include a right hand side in your expression which in this case will turn out to be zero.
{rhs1, mat1} = CoefficientArrays[ex, vec1] // Normal;
 mat1 // MatrixForm


This has pulled out the b vector. Now to pull out the c vector we go again.
{rhs2, mat2} = CoefficientArrays[mat, vec2] // Normal;


Finally we check that the matrices formed are the same as the original expressioin.
ex2 = (mat2 . vec2) . vec1;
 ex == ex2 // Simplify

True

So  I hope this is what you wanted.

Please check the edited. Your answer works for the 33 case, but not for the 44 or any general case.

expr = a1  b1  c1 + a4  b2  c1 + a7  b3  c1 + a2  b1  c2 + 
  a5  b2  c2 + a8  b3  c2 + a3  b1  c3 + a6  b2  c3 + a9  b3  c3

n = 3; (*number of symbols in each term*)
expr2 = List @@ expr
A = expr2[[1 ;; 3, 2]]
B = Union@expr2[[;; , 3]]
M = ArrayReshape[expr2[[;; , 1]], {n, n}]
(MatrixForm[M] . MatrixForm[A]) . MatrixForm[B]


 Expand[(M . A) . B]
 a1 b1 c1 + a4 b2 c1 + a7 b3 c1 + a2 b1 c2 + a5 b2 c2 + a8 b3 c2 + 
  a3 b1 c3 + a6 b2 c3 + a9 b3 c3

Check
Expand[(M . A) . B] === expr
(*True*)


First, please explain each step, eg List@@, ;;, Array Reshape. 2nd, vector A should be in a row on the left, looking like: A.M.B.

Could you try the edited example? You answer does not work for the 4*4 operation with different symbols in each term.

@SciJewel I used the same format as Hugh to reduce confusion. He used (mat2 . vec2) . vec1; and that is what I used. Other permutation might not lead to an answer. Will check. The way I did this is by reverse engineering. I made generic matrix and generic two vectors and multiplied them as above, and by looking at result, found the what each should be given the input you had. i.e. found mapping between the input and the generic output.

Ok thanks! Could you also try the edited example? Your code doesn't work on this example.

In your case solution seems don't exist. One could try it as follows.
input = a1  b1  c1 + a4  b2  c1 + a7  b3  c1 + a2  b1  c2 + 
   a5  b2  c2 + a8  b3  c2 + a3  b1  c3 + a6  b2  c3 + a9  b3  c3;

formalExpression = (a /@ Range[3]) . 
   Partition[c /@ Range[3*3], 3] . (b /@ Range[3]) // Expand

vars = Variables[input]
SolveAlways[formalExpression == input, vars]
(* {} *)

With some of variables omitted solution can be found. For example,
SolveAlways[formalExpression == input, 
 Flatten[{vars[[1 ;; 2]], vars[[4 ;; 8]], vars[[10 ;; 12]], 
   vars[[14 ;; 15]]}]]

